# Ember Data - How to observe for parent model change from child model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I want to observe for changes in a `isParentValid`-property of parent's model, and update the `isChildValid`-property of child model base on that.

I want to do something like below.

**Parent Model**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    child: DS.hasMany('child', { inverse: null }),
    isParentValid: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false})
});
```

**child Model**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    isChildValid: Ember.computed('parent.isParentValid', {
    get: function () {
        //return true if isParentValid property is true
        //else return false
     })
});
```

Tried few ways not able to figure it out. I am not even sure that if it is even possible

Comment: I think you should have belongsTo relationship in the child pointing to parent, that way your isChildValid can be just alias to the parent's isParentValid property.